# gozirra-0.4.1 no longer available via maven

Tags: java, maven

I used to successfully use the following in my pom:

`<dependency><groupId>net.ser1</groupId><artifactId>gozirra-client</artifactId><version>0.4.1</version></dependency>`

But now I get a missing artefact error.

If I try to download manually via https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.ser1/gozirra-client/0.4.1 (linked to https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/net/ser1/gozirra-client/0.4.1/gozirra-client-0.4.1.jar for the jar), this now gives a 401 because repo.spring.io have changed their policies.

Are these two things related, and if so is there an alternative source I can point my pom at?